# Error Ljava/awt/Dimension when use getImageDimension aoache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, awt

I have this error when use getImageDimension in apache poi to get image size

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture.getImageDimension()Ljava/awt/Dimension;
    at image.XlsxTest.main(XlsxTest.java:47)
```

How i solve this problem?

Comment: Change the source code so it doesn't get the exception.

Comment: What version of Apache POI? What call exactly are you making? What JVM?

Comment: apache poi 3.12 and java 8

Comment: What happens if you upgrade to a more recent Apache POI?

Comment: Works fine when change version of poi and poi-xml <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.17</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>